# Video doesn't play in IE browser

Tags: php

I created php web application like 9gag, the problem is if any one view in chrome it's run nice but in internet explore it does not playing after pressing refresh it works fine. Plz help

Demo link http://myzonevideos.com/play.php?vid=8

Comment: Code? Html? Fiddle? Without it you're asking us to be clairvoyant

Comment: You're link works on Win7+IE11

Comment: Some times it not run well, after I refresh only it start playing

Comment: Not having gone rthrough the complete 'show source' of your link. Timeing issues: 99% of the time it because code is executed before the DOM is ready. Are you using any 'document.ready' style to start any code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer is a one crazy lame browser that ever been created. It must be something about headers of the video you are trying to view on browser.

Also you didn't provide the information that what you are using to play the videos, flash or HTML5?